# Server tag not well formed - Create table with server control using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to create a `table` that has some dynamic data and some server controls. I need server controls so that they will be accessed in code behind. I am creating `table` in `JQuery`. My code is as below.

```
function createLeaveDetails(formattedArray) {
                    var leaveTable = "<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' style='width: 435px'>";
                    leaveTable += "<tr> <th>Date</th> <th>Full Day</th> <th>Half Day</th> </tr>";
                    for (i = 0; i < formattedArray.length; i++) {
                        leaveTable += "<tr> <td>" + formattedArray[i] + "</td> <td><asp:RadioButton ID='radHalf" + i + " runat='server' GroupName='grp" + i + "' /></td>";
                        leaveTable += "<td><asp:RadioButton ID='radFull" + i + " runat='server' GroupName='grp" + i + "' /></td> </tr>";
                    }
                    leaveTable = +"</table>"

                    $("#tblLeaveDetails").append();
                }
```

but at run-time its giving `The server tag is not well formed.` error on line

`leaveTable += "<tr> <td>" + formattedArray[i] + "</td> <td><asp:RadioButton ID='radHalf" + i + " runat='server' GroupName='grp" + i + "' /></td>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you cannot create **"server"** controls from client side (i.e. JavaScript / Jquery). As the Browser does not understand the server tag. The Asp View engine render that server control to the HTML control accordingly. So all you can do is you create basic HTML elements from the client side scripting. 
Create

```
<input type='radio'></input>
```

instead of

```
<asp:RadioButton />
```

As you need the value at the server you can create an Hidden Field and put the selected value of the input radio in that hidden field from JavaScript  / Jquery. as follows

```
$('#yourRadiobuttonlist').change(function(){
    yourHiddenField.value = $('#yourRadiobuttonlist :selected').val();
});
```

And at server side you can access the Hidden Field value for the desired selected value of the radio button.

Hope it helps....